# Show that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(x_{k})$ has a subsequence that converges to a value of $f$

Tags: analysis

Let $f:[a,b] \to R$ continuous,$x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n},\ldots \in [a,b]$. Show that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(x_{k})$ has a subsequence that converges to a value of $f$.
How can I show this??

Comment: What can you say about $f([a,b])$? What sort of set is that?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sequence $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf(x_k)$.

By continuity of $f$ and compactness of $[a,b]$ it follows that there is a $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(x)|\leq M$ all $x \in [a,b]$. Why?

Now, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have   $|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf(x_k)|\leq\frac{1}{n}Mn=M$. Why?

Finally, apply the [Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).